# Migrating RecyclerView from Activity to Fragment - can't use findViewById

Tags: android

I copied the following code from the MainActivity to a separate fragment, but I can't get `findViewById` to work:
I get "cannot resolve method findViewById(int)"
these are the related files:

**Also as a beginner, could you let me know if there's a general problem with my code that needs to fixed?

MyFragment.java:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {


    public myFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

        // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
        // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // use a linear layout manager
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        //placeholder data
        String[] myDataset = new String[16];
        myDataset[0] = "Data0";
        myDataset[1] = "Data1";
        myDataset[2] = "Data2";
        myDataset[3] = "Data3";
        myDataset[4] = "Data4";
        myDataset[5] = "Data5";
        myDataset[6] = "Data6";
        myDataset[7] = "Data7";
        myDataset[8] = "Data8";
        myDataset[9] = "Data9";
        myDataset[10] = "Data10";
        myDataset[11] = "Data11";
        myDataset[12] = "Data12";
        myDataset[13] = "Data13";
        myDataset[14] = "Data14";
        myDataset[15] = "Data15";

        // specify an adapter (see also next example)
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    }

}
```

MyAdapter.java:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private String[] mDataset;

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView upTv;
        public TextView downTv;
        public View layout;
        public MyViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            layout = v;
            upTv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.upTv);
            downTv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.downTv);
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                     int viewType) {


        View v =  LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false);

        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        holder.upTv.setText(mDataset[position]);
        holder.downTv.setText(mDataset[position]);
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.length;
    }
}
```

fragment_my.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

my_text_view.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/downTv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"

        android:text="downTv"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/upTv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="upTv"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);
```

You cannot add more code after the return statement. You will need to take the reference of the inflated view and use it to find the reference of child views.

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);

mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

// other code

return rootView;
```

Comment: Thank you, now the app won't crash, but I do not see any data? All I get is empty background. Why won't the data display? Please help me with this one. On the original app (with only activity) the data displays, but here none

Answer (score 0):

A really good way to use fragments is to initialize certain variables(e.g- activity,context,root view etc) associated with the parent activity when you switch to a fragment.
for example you can do sth like,

```
private Context context;
        private MainActivity activity; //Let MainActivity is your parent activity
        private View view; //fields kept inside the fragment class,now we need to keep them initialized

    //initialize activity/context from onAttach
        @Override
        public void onAttach(Context c) {
        super.onAttach(c);

                Activity a;

                context=c;
                if (c instanceof Activity){
                    a=(Activity) c;
                    if(a instanceof MainActivity)
                        activity=(MainActivity) a;
                }

            }
//initialize view from onViewCreated
     @Override
        public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
           this.view=view;
        }
```

now you can use them wherever u want inside the fragment class without triggering any nullptrs and other stuff

e.g- you can go

```
this.view.findViewById(your_resId); 
this.activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
```

etc and a lot of other stuffs when you need ,using these fields you initialized

also specifically in this case of using recyclerView dont forget to call,
`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` whenever you think the list you are showing in the recyclerView went through some change.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to comment so i am writing this as answer to your comment.
You need to notify adapter using below code.

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```